# how can i create a Custom Query with Spring Data JPA with shared fields?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to create a query method to bring some shared fields in other entities using **Spring Data Rest**, like the example below: I'm using Native Query, because i don't know how to make it with JPA when the fields are not in an Entity so i'm trying to make it with Native SQL.

```
@Entity
public class Citizen{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_city")
    private City city;

    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class City{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String cityName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city")
    private List<Citizen> citizens;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_country")
    private Country country;

    //getter and setters
}

@Entity
public class Country{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String countryName;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country")
    private List<City> cities;

    // getter and setters
}

@RepositoryRestResource(path = "users")
public interface CustomQueries extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Citizen, Long>{

    @RestResource(path = "users-custom-query")
    @Query(value = "SELECT c1.name, c2.name, c3.name FROM Citizen AS c1 INNER JOIN City AS c2 ON "+
           "c1.fk_city = c2.id INNER JOIN Country AS c3 ON "+
           "c2.fk_country = c3.id", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Object[]> getCitizensInCitiesAndCountries(Pageable p);

}
```

The problem: this is giving me and error, i assume that is because there is no entity "mapped" to that kind of response or some DTO to share those attributes, i don't know if it is because the generic on `PagingAndSorting<Citizen, Long>` or because of the return type  `Page<Object[]>...` but that query works fine in MySQL but JPA rejects it :c, How to do it to bring those fields in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) using an interface

Create an interface

```
public interface CitizenData{

    String geName();
    String geCityName();
    String geCountryName();
}
```

Set alias on the selected column for interface mapping

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c1.name AS name, c2.name As cityName, c3.name AS countryName FROM Citizen AS c1 INNER JOIN City AS c2 ON "+
           "c1.fk_city = c2.id INNER JOIN Country AS c3 ON "+
           "c2.fk_country = c3.id", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<CitizenData> getCitizensInCitiesAndCountries(Pageable p);
```

Comment: im getting an error with the Type in `PagingAndSortingRepository<T,ID>` this should be the same `CitizenData` ?, i mean another interface with `PagingAndSortingRepositoru<CitizenData, Long>`